# Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu Insert Media Tool Error. Can you help me?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Summary of Findings:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zSXHpdPqZJ/

I have Windows 7 installed at first then I decided to install Ubuntu, but after the installation there is no bootloader or grub.

I mean only blackscreen and a couple of text saying Insert media Tool.

What should I do? I don't want to format the whole Hard Drive because I have so many precious file in it.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the installation supposed to be a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu? If so, the grub from Ubuntu should be able to detect the Windows 7 and add it to the startup options. Or maybe you already notice the Windows 7 during installation of Ubuntu.

I had a very similar issue several years ago but it was actually my own fault. I set up a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu and used the grub as the boot manager instead of Windows's. Later I tried to uninstall Ubuntu by deleting the Ubuntu disk within Window 7 and of course I was doomed as the grub was deleted as well. However I found some information saying that I can **modify the MBR to manually point to the loader of the remaining Windows 7**. Can't remember if I used a Windows 7 installation disk to enter recovery mode but I remember the modification was in the black screen. Anyway it worked out for me eventually.